# How to specify height of waveform in Modelsim/Questasim?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, modelsim, questasim

I'm using QuestaSim 70.7b;
And I can not change the height of waveform signal.. 
I've tried many options, like this:

```
add wave -radix hex -format analog-step -scale 100 -height 100 -color gold /bin_top_tb/clk
```

But nothing happen, just height of the name signal is changed, like shown below

[image]

*thanks to dave_59, to change the height you should go to Tools -> Edit Preferences and change WaveFont and then footerFont exactly at such sequence, then click apply and ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to change the height of individual digital signal. You use the main preferences to select a larger Wave Window text font, and the size of the waveform gets scaled to match the wave label.