# In Modelsim/Questasim is there a way to increase the thickness of the wave lines?

Tags: modelsim, questasim

Using Modelsim/Questasim 10.6b with a 4K monitor makes it difficult to see the lines for signals, especially std_logic signals, vectors are a little better.

I was able to increase text size via edit->preferences but haven't found anything similar for wave "weight" or "thickness".

Comment: You can try change height of waveform - it might help you: [*click*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56306120/how-to-specify-height-of-waveform-in-modelsim-questasim)

Answer (score 0):

I've struggled with this for years and it seems its not possible.

You can change the format to "literal" which makes it slightly easier to see when there has been a thin pulse but otherwise - sorry I don't think its possible.

Perhaps raising an enhancement request with Mentor will help for a future version.

Answer (score 0):

Not a 4K monitor user, but have you tried modifying settings at Tools -> Edit preferences -> "By Name" tab and looking for wave?

I've just figured out that going to Tools -> Edit preferences -> On fonts section look for "waveFont", i can increase waveform size font. Which, by default, is tahoma 8